# Stored procedure to select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure that takes an argument

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[myprocedure](@myName char(20))
as
   select param1
   from table1
   where name = @myName
```

Now this is working but when I try to select parameters from other tables it is not working I tried like this after the first select

```
(Select param2 table2)
```

But I get

> MS 512, Level 16, State 1, Procedure candidate, Line 3
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Does anyone know hot to use the select to get values from more than one table? Thanks

Comment: Does that mean you want Param1 from table1 and Param2 from table 2?
In that case use Union all

Comment: how would Union all be used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `IN` operator instead of = after Where clause

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[myprocedure](@myName char(20))
as

select param1
from table1
where name = @myName

---
select param1
from table1
where name IN (Select param2 from table2)
```

Edit

```
select param1
from table1
where name = @myName
union
Select param2
from table2
```

Note that `UNION` is going to remove duplicate values after combining resultset from table1 and table2.

To keep duplicate values , use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Yeah but how can I match the name with @myName

Comment: So you want to match name column from table1 with param2 column of table2 as well as with paramaeter @myName ?

Comment: I want to match name colum from table1 with @myName and to return param2 from table 2